Ubuntu Repository not working
I have setup ubuntu repository but when I am trying apt update or apt-get update on client server however it is not working.
root@server:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Err:3 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ]
Ign:4 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en
Ign:6 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:4 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [14.1 MB]
Get:5 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en [5,652 kB]
Get:6 http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [286 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ip/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@server:/etc/apt#

The error report that release fine not found however release file is available

Are you sure that the PPA repo supports your release of Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

I see this file in sources.list.d  : root@cusvltst01:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main

Can some one please advice .

Can you edit the question to include your Ubuntu version? The output of the lsb_release -a command should help you if you're unsure
